# a + b mod n vs. a xor b mod n

Tags: performance, random, bitwise-xor

I'm procedurally generating a World in a Game and therefore use 2 equivalent pseudo-random generators (linear congruential) for x and y axis (giving both a different seed of course).

Now to be able to create different worlds I want to combine both pseudo-random values (e.g. both between 0 and 10) for each position (x,y).

I first thought of hashing (to generally equally hit each number from 0 to 10), but then found that XORing both ints might be more performant (o.c. you might call that hashing too)
Now I still want to generate values between 0 and 10. So I would do:

(1) (r1 ^ r2) % 11.
( ^ beeing bitwise XOR)

And here I was wondering if that is equivalent to

(2) (r1 + r2) % 11

And which of both would be more performant. I'd say (1) because it does not carry bits?

Comment: In the words of Eric Lippert - [race your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: `I'm procedurally generating a World in a Game`-- I highly doubt the performance difference between the xor and addition operators here will be noticeable or even measurable in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: On most modern processors addition and xor cost exactly the same (both a very fast). If you want to speed up this code, it is probably much more important to focus on the modulus which is significantly more costly (although this is a constant) or on the vectorization of this expression.

Comment: Yeah I know that the modulus would rather be the problem here. And especially in generating the world there should not be a noticable performance difference. I would anyway only optimize it if there is a bottleneck. The world generation was rather mentioned to give a context for the question, if both is equivalent. I think they are, but I might miss an important point regarding the carried bit? More detailed it would be: a+b != a ^ b, but is a+b mod n == a ^ b mod n